# OpenCV error in android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have successully compiled opencv test example (videoemulation), but on running on emulator its giving me strange error:

```
 06-25 15:36:34.526: D/dalvikvm(621): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.siprop.opencv  /lib/libopencv.so 0x405139b0
 06-25 15:36:34.566: D/dalvikvm(621): Added shared lib /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/lib/libopencv.so 0x405139b0
 06-25 15:36:34.566: D/dalvikvm(621): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/lib/libopencv.so 0x405139b0, skipping init
 06-25 15:36:34.619: D/VideoEmulation(621): mOpenCVAction = TRACK_SINGLE_FACE
 06-25 15:36:34.627: D/VideoEmulation(621): onResume
 06-25 15:36:34.627: D/VideoEmulation(621): initFaceDetect
 06-25 15:36:34.637: E/CVJNI(621): Error loading cascade.
 06-25 15:36:34.637: D/VideoEmulation(621): Failed to initialize face detection!
```

Is it that I am not loading the functions. Please guide me.

This is the OpenCV Java file:

```
  public class OpenCV {
       static {
       System.loadLibrary("opencv");
  }

public native byte[] findContours(int[] data, int w, int h);
public native boolean createSocketCapture(String address, String port, int width, int height);
public native void releaseSocketCapture();
public native boolean grabSourceImageFromCapture();
public native byte[] getSourceImage();
public native boolean setSourceImage(int[] data, int w, int h);
public native boolean initFaceDetection(String cascadePath);
public native void releaseFaceDetection();
public native boolean highlightFaces();
public native Rect[] findAllFaces();
public native Rect findSingleFace();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all your native (c++) functions are in block:

```
extern "C" {
...
}
```

Comment: ok got it corrected..i tried all the methods, and yes functions weren't in extern c, have included those but that too didn't solved the problem then, i looked into the problem in detail No JNI_OnLoad found, on seeing the code i found JNI_OnLoad function was also not defined but even that too didn't solved the problem, then i updated the NDK to r8 and again followed all the steps and even that too didn't solved the problem. So after trying all these i went to official site and downloaded the opencv and that run like water. I hope some one else don't do the mistake i did. Thanks Astor :)